# How to create a mock of list of a custom data type in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class User with the following definition :

```
class User {

  Integer id;
  String name;
  String addr;

  //getters and setters

}
```

Now while testing a function, I am required to return a list of mocked Users for a stub, something like:

```
Mockito.when(userService.getListOfUsers()).thenReturn(mockList);
```

Now this mockList could be created as the following :

```
List mockList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
```

But this mockList could be a list of anything. I won't be able to ensure its type. Is there a way to create list of :

```
List<User> mockListForUser = Mockito.mock(?);
```

Comment: `List<User> mockListForUser = Mockito.mock(List.class);`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably want to populate a normal list with your mocked objects. E.g.

```
List<User> mockList = new ArrayList<>();

User mockUser1 = Mockito.mock(User.class);
// ...    

mockList.add(mockUser1);
// etc.
```

Note that by default, Mockito returns an empty collection for any mocked methods that returns a collection. So if you just want to return an empty list, Mockito will already do that for you.

Comment: So basically I can't make verifications on the list with this implementation?

Comment: @Sourabh What do you want to verify?

Comment: In case I have a service that goes to work on the mocked list that I just returned using when().thenReturn(), I might want to verify the interactions on the list.

Comment: @Sourabh It probably isn't a good idea to care how the service uses the list. Instead, check the results of the service methods (which may involve testing to see if something happened with each of the items in your list).

Comment: @Sourabh Imagine taking an exam about making pasta. The instructor gives you some ingredients and judges you on the taste of the final dish. He doesn't care in what order you chop the ingredients, but he cares what you produce. Similar with mocking - only test *just enough* to be sure your results are correct. Caring about how the list is used is like caring about the chopping.

Comment: okay something like Mockito.verify(mockList.get(0), mockUser1) or Mockito.verify(mockList.get(0), atLeast(2)) ?

Answer (score 10):

Use the `@Mock` annotation in your test since Mockito can use type reflection:

```
@Mock
private ArrayList<User> mockArrayList;
```

Comment: Isn't this pretty much List<User> mockArrayList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class) ?

Comment: Roughly, except it is much sexier and you do not handle the type which is your issue here: you let Mockito do it for you.

Comment: Okay also can I make such declarations within a class method or do I have to make it a class variable?

Comment: @Sourabh Usually you declare it as an attribute in your junit test class

Comment: When trying to use this in Kotlin, I am getting the following issue: 
"VM does not not support modification of given type". Any clue if this is supported or how to do an alternative using @Mock?